# Can you add the Collection Helper to your inventory using cheats?

Tags: the-sims-3

I am looking to add the Collection Helper from the Lifetime Reward to my inventory, but I'm not sure where to find it when you use things like buydebug or testingCheatsEnabled. Is it even possible in the first place to get this item this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lifetime Reward Cheat](http://www.carls-sims-3-guide.com/lifetimerewards/?cmtx_page=1)

Press Control + Shift + C and a console will come up. Type **testingcheatsenabled true**. Execute the Rewards Cheat by heading to the Lifetime Rewards tab of the interface. There you will see a treasure chest icon. **Hold Control and click in the blank space just to the right of the treasure chest.** Move your mouse around while quickly clicking to find the sweet spot. Once you hit it, click like mad to increase your current Sim or Pet's Lifetime Points. -Carl

Comment: Alright, it's an alternative to what I was looking for, but this works. Thanks!

Comment: NP, I guess there is no cheat, that's why it's like this.